# How to handle response in GraphQl and Neo4js

Tags: react-native, neo4j, graphql, response, express-graphql

I am not able to get response back if the email is already exist in DB.
I tried below example code. But I am getting null in response(see image)
[image: in status there should Email exist message I am sending from query]
Here is my api

```
{"query": "mutation authenticateUser($Phone: String!,$Email: String!, $type: String!, $otp: Int!) { authenticateUser(Phone : $Phone,Email: $Email,type : $type, otp : $otp) { status } }", "variables" : this.authenticateUserObj}
```

and Backend code :

```
router.post('/graphql', express_graphql(request => {
return {
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
}
```

}));

```
var root = {
authenticateUser : authenticateUser
};

var schema = buildSchema(`
type Mutation {
   authenticateUser(Phone:  String, Email: String,type: String,otp: Int,status: String): Authenticate
}
type Authenticate {
    Phone : String
    Email : String
    Type : String
    otp : Int
    status: String
}
```

`);

```
var authenticateUser = function({Phone, Email, type, otp}) {
db.cypher({
    query: "MATCH (n:userNodes) where n.Email='"+Email+"' RETURN count(*) as total",
}, function (err, results) {
    if(results[0]['total'] > 0)
    {
        return {status: "Email already exist"};
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

do you get value in results[0] ? is it object or array ?

Comment: Yes, Getting result as count(Total) in integer.

Comment: My only question is why it's (return {status: "Email already exist"};) not sending response back inside db.cypher? If I returns response outside  db.cypher it's works like exact I want.